# Custom Function going disable after importing anything

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel, excel-web-addins

I have created a addin project for creating excel custom function. When I am importing anything like module or file in function.js file, my custom functions are going disable. After going disable its working fine. So my question is why its going disable after importing any module or file.

Images are given below.

[Before importing module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm7Xy.png)

[After importing module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5GUC.png)

Comment: I tried to reproduce this behavior but it appears to work fine. Did you make any other changes besides adding the import? I assume you added jwt-decode to the package.json file? If you are testing on Office on Windows, you can [turn on logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/testing/runtime-logging) to get more information. Sometime you need to [clear the cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache) on Office on Windows while coding and testing an add-in.

Comment: okay this will help me a lot.